# Redirect IE7 browser BUT NOT windows phone 7

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, windows-mobile

I am not able to debug and test windows 7 phone, however 
I have following code

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/index_ie.html" /><script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[ window.top.location = "/index_ie.html";]]></script><![endif]-->
```

However I just heard from a friend that this is affecting his windows mobile phone, which has this agent:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0)
```

Is there a way to exclude windows mobile browser from triggering this redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His Windows phone has IE Mobile 7, so it makes sense that a lte IE7 evaluates to true and triggers the redirect. You could try this:

```
<!--[if !IEMobile]>
<![if lte IE 7]>      
...
<![endif]>
<![endif]-->
```

See here for more ideas: [Conditional Comments to target Windows Phone 7 Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865130/conditional-comments-to-target-windows-phone-7-internet-explorer-9) and [Is there a way to target Windows Mobile 7.5 browser using conditional comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500684/is-there-a-way-to-target-windows-mobile-7-5-browser-using-conditional-comments)